# How can I escape parenthesis in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, parentheses

I am used to coding Java in Eclipse where I can escape (go to the other side of) a parenthesis with the tab key.

I cannot find a way to do this while coding JavaScript in WebStorm. It is slowing down my coding a lot, as I have to click with my mouse to start writing something new.

Is there an easy way to escape parenthesis in WebStorm?

Comment: This is a fantastic question. I hope someone has an answer. If anyone has any other resources on how to become more efficient with WebStorm, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

not currently possible, please vote for [IDEABKL-6984](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984)